# Fulltext index on MySQL view or correct the way to search in joined tables

Tags: mysql, join, view, indexing, full-text-search

Although this topic has been widely discussed, it left me very confused and I haven't been able to distill the correct answer. Could you please help me in the right direction? Thanks.

I've got this setup: table `page` is connected to table `widget`by means of a reference table `widget_to_page`:

**page (p)**
`sid | title | content`
**widget (w)**
`sid | content`
**widget_to_page (wtp)**
`sid | page_sid | widget_sid`

I've created a fulltext index on `p.title`, `p.content`, `w.content`

Next up, I would like to the page-widget-combination:

```
SELECT *, MATCH(p.title, p.content, w.content) AGAINST("'.$keyword.'") AS score 
FROM page p, widget w, widget_to_page wtp
WHERE MATCH(p.title, p.content, w.content) AGAINST("'.$keyword.'")
AND p.sid = wtp.page_sid
AND w.sid = wtp.widget_sid
ORDER BY score DESC
```

Some remarks:

1. This obviously doesn't work... :-)
2. I've been reading that if I use this syntax to join the tables (or use a JOIN) statement, that it would cause MySQL to ignore the fulltext index. What is the correct method?

An alternative I've tried out was to create a MySQL view out of the following statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM page p, widget w, widget_to_page wtp
WHERE p.sid = wtp.page_sid
AND w.sid = wtp.widget_sid
```

But this also does not seem to work. Some people speak of creating a fulltext index on this particular view, but I can't find any options in PHPMyAdmin to do this and I do not know if this is even possible.

In short... what is the best practice in such a situation? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A FULLTEXT index can include multiple columns, but those columns have to be in the same table. So you will not be able to cover those 3 columns from 2 tables in a single index. You will need at least 2 indexes to accomplish that.

Also, FULLTEXT indexes only work with the MyISAM storage engine, so if you are using a transactional engine like InnoDB this will not work. You should read the manual to learn about other features and limitations of fulltext indexes (including boolean mode, stopwords, etc.):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html

Assuming you are using MyISAM, you can create 1 fulltext index on (p.title,p.content) and another fulltext index on (w.content), then query the two indexes separately and use UNION ALL to combine the results.

The resulting query will be something like this, but you'll need to tweak it to meet your specific requirements:

```
select page_sid, page_title, sum(score) as total_score
from 
(
SELECT p.sid as page_sid,p.title as page_title,NULL as widget_sid, 
  MATCH(p.title, p.content) AGAINST("'.$keyword.'") AS score 
FROM page p
WHERE MATCH(p.title, p.content) AGAINST("'.$keyword.'")
UNION
SELECT p.sid as page_sid,p.title as page_title,w.sid as widget_sid, 
  MATCH(w.content) AGAINST("'.$keyword.'") AS score 
FROM page p
  inner join widget_to_page wtp on p.sid = wtp.page_sid
  inner join widget w on w.sid = wtp.widget_sid
WHERE MATCH(w.content) AGAINST("'.$keyword.'")
) as sub_query
group by page_sid
ORDER BY total_score DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I keep getting errors `Unknown column 'w.sid' in 'field list'`, regarding to the first instance of `w.sid`. If I remove `w.sid as widget_sid,` I get an error `Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list`. 

What do you propose?

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo before. I had switched w.sid and NULL. I fixed it now.

Comment: Also, please note that you need to create two new fulltext indexes: one on (p.title, p.content) and one on (w.content).

Comment: Thank you, Ike. I double checked, I've two indexes, one on p.title, p.content and one on w.content. However, I keep getting an error: 
`Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list`

Do you know what it can be?

Comment: Are they both `FULLTEXT` indexes? Run `SHOW CREATE TABLE page\G` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE widget\G` and confirm that they have the proper FULLTEXT indexes.

Comment: I ran these queries. The output is here:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/262439/page.pdf
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/262439/widget.pdf

Could you please double check it? I'm too new in this to be sure.

Comment: The problem is that you have extra columns in your indexes: meta_keywords and meta_description. The column list int he index needs to exactly match the column list in your `MATCH` statement. So either add those columns to your `MATCH` statement if you want to search them, or add two new indexes without them if you do not want to search those columns.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ike. I always try to simplify the problem when I ask a question here. I did not realize it had to be exactly the same. I know a lot more now. Have a great night!

Comment: @IkeWalker We just tried FULLINDEX search on a InnoDB engine and that worked. Is your information that does not wok on InnoDB wrong?

Comment: Hi @PrimozRome. At the time I answered this question (4.5 years ago!) InnoDB did not support FULLTEXT indexes. That changed in MySQL 5.6, so if you are using 5.6 or newer you can create FULLTEXT indexes on InnoDB tables.